# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton

Tags: java, javafx

I added JFoenix to IntelliJ and SceneBuilder.
It works in SceneBuilder but while compling the project it doesn't recognize any JFoenix.controls

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXCheckBox
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2931)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2920)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2861)
```

Comment: What build tool are you using? Maven, gradle, ant, other?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Have you got the [jfoenix](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix) dependency? Note, [How to Include In Maven Project](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix#how-to-include-in-maven-project).

Comment: I got jfoenix  jar file

Comment: Basically, you're not including JFoenix on the classpath (or modulepath) when building and/or executing your code. You'll have to figure out how to fix that. Note that including the library in _Scene Builder_ is not enough, _IntelliJ_ needs to know about it too. If you're using a build too such as Maven or Gradle simply add the dependency to your build script. If you're not using a build tool, add the library to _IntelliJ_.

Comment: Thank you i solved the problem by adding   < --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml > in VM OPTION

Comment: If your project setup is not having module import means add the jfoenix jar to your project using add external jar in the properties option

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the occasion, but incase someone else has a similar issue and your dependencies are all good/setup, you may want to look at your module-info.java file contents.
All dependencies needed to be added there like so:

```
module xyz.myapp {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires com.jfoenix;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens xyz.myapp to javafx.fxml;
    exports xyz.myapp;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive, Because running your code in mine. Didn't actually resolve the issue